# Ajax : How to Loop through Huge JSON data

Tags: php, json

I receive the below Json Data in an ajax response... I dont know how to traverse it I wana loop through it and make an array out of it, Which I will gonna be using in the HTML DOM also I wana Cache this data for No More Ajax requests if data is already available...

How Can I do that,
I have Tried to do it with $.each(data, function(key,value){ ---- }). But the problem is looping through the data I wanna put a for Loop and Inside it I wanna Populate some other array or object...

Does that Make any sense, Can we do that?

```
{"CountryCode":"ABW","Language":"Dutch"}{"CountryCode":"ABW","Language":"English"}{"CountryCode":"ABW","Language":"Papiamento"}{"CountryCode":"ABW","Language":"Spanish"}{"CountryCode":"AFG","Language":"Balochi"}{"CountryCode":"AFG","Language":"Dari"}{"CountryCode":"AFG","Language":"Pashto"}{"CountryCode":"AFG","Language":"Turkmenian"}{"CountryCode":"AFG","Language":"Uzbek"}{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Ambo"}{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Chokwe"}{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Kongo"}{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Luchazi"}{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Luimbe-nganguela"}{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Luvale"}{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Mbundu"}{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Nyaneka-nkhumbi"}{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Ovimbundu"}{"CountryCode":"AIA","Language":"English"}{"CountryCode":"ALB","Language":"Albaniana"}{"CountryCode":"ALB","Language":"Greek"}{"CountryCode":"ALB","Language":"Macedonian"}{"CountryCode":"AND","Language":"Catalan"}{"CountryCode":"AND","Language":"French"}{"CountryCode":"AND","Language":"Portuguese"}{"CountryCode":"AND","Language":"Spanish"}{"CountryCode":"ANT","Language":"Dutch"}{"CountryCode":"ANT","Language":"English"}{"CountryCode":"ANT","Language":"Papiamento"}{"CountryCode":"ARE","Language":"Arabic"}{"CountryCode":"ARE","Language":"Hindi"}{"CountryCode":"ARG","Language":"Indian Languages"}{"CountryCode":"ARG","Language":"Italian"}{"CountryCode":"ARG","Language":"Spanish"}{"CountryCode":"ARM","Language":"Armenian"}{"CountryCode":"ARM","Language":"Azerbaijani"}{"CountryCode":"ASM","Language":"English"}{"CountryCode":"ASM","Language":"Samoan"}{"CountryCode":"ASM","Language":"Tongan"}{"CountryCode":"ATG","Language":"Creole English"}{"CountryCode":"ATG","Language":"English"}{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Arabic"}{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Canton Chinese"}{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"English"}{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"German"}{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Greek"}{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Italian"}{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Serbo-Croatian"}{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Vietnamese"}{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Czech"}{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"German"}{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Hungarian"}{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Polish"}{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Romanian"}{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Serbo-Croatian"}{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Slovene"}{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Turkish"}{"CountryCode":"AZE","Language":"Armenian"}{"CountryCode":"AZE","Language":"Azerbaijani"}{"CountryCode":"AZE","Language":"Lezgian"}{"CountryCode":"AZE","Language":"Russian"}{"CountryCode":"BDI","Language":"French"}{"CountryCode":"BDI","Language":"Kirundi"}{"CountryCode":"BDI","Language":"Swahili"}{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"Arabic"}{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"Dutch"}{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"French"}{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"German"}{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"Italian"}{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"Turkish"}{"CountryCode":"BEN","Language":"Adja"}{"CountryCode":"BEN","Language":"Aizo"}
```

Comment: No, your question does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved in two steps:

1) convert your json data to a php String
2) iterate over that array:

step 1) convert to array

```
$arr = json_decode($jsondata);
```

step 2) iterate over array

```
arrayRecurssive($arr);

function arrayRecurssive($arr){

    foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
        if(is_array($val)){
            echo "$key\n";
            arrayRecurssive($val);
        }else{
           echo "$key\n";
           echo "$val\n";
        }

    }
}
```

in my example above im using  '\n' as my new line, but that may as well be `<br/>`.  further formatting of the output is left as an exercise for the coder :-)

Answer (score 1):

The json data appears to be badly formatted. It should be:

```
[{"CountryCode":"ABW","Language":"Dutch"},{"CountryCode":"ABW","Language":"English"},{"CountryCode":"ABW","Language":"Papiamento"},{"CountryCode":"ABW","Language":"Spanish"},{"CountryCode":"AFG","Language":"Balochi"},{"CountryCode":"AFG","Language":"Dari"},{"CountryCode":"AFG","Language":"Pashto"},{"CountryCode":"AFG","Language":"Turkmenian"},{"CountryCode":"AFG","Language":"Uzbek"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Ambo"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Chokwe"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Kongo"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Luchazi"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Luimbe-nganguela"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Luvale"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Mbundu"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Nyaneka-nkhumbi"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Ovimbundu"},{"CountryCode":"AIA","Language":"English"},{"CountryCode":"ALB","Language":"Albaniana"},{"CountryCode":"ALB","Language":"Greek"},{"CountryCode":"ALB","Language":"Macedonian"},{"CountryCode":"AND","Language":"Catalan"},{"CountryCode":"AND","Language":"French"},{"CountryCode":"AND","Language":"Portuguese"},{"CountryCode":"AND","Language":"Spanish"},{"CountryCode":"ANT","Language":"Dutch"},{"CountryCode":"ANT","Language":"English"},{"CountryCode":"ANT","Language":"Papiamento"},{"CountryCode":"ARE","Language":"Arabic"},{"CountryCode":"ARE","Language":"Hindi"},{"CountryCode":"ARG","Language":"Indian Languages"},{"CountryCode":"ARG","Language":"Italian"},{"CountryCode":"ARG","Language":"Spanish"},{"CountryCode":"ARM","Language":"Armenian"},{"CountryCode":"ARM","Language":"Azerbaijani"},{"CountryCode":"ASM","Language":"English"},{"CountryCode":"ASM","Language":"Samoan"},{"CountryCode":"ASM","Language":"Tongan"},{"CountryCode":"ATG","Language":"Creole English"},{"CountryCode":"ATG","Language":"English"},{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Arabic"},{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Canton Chinese"},{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"English"},{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"German"},{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Greek"},{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Italian"},{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Serbo-Croatian"},{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Vietnamese"},{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Czech"},{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"German"},{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Hungarian"},{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Polish"},{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Romanian"},{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Serbo-Croatian"},{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Slovene"},{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Turkish"},{"CountryCode":"AZE","Language":"Armenian"},{"CountryCode":"AZE","Language":"Azerbaijani"},{"CountryCode":"AZE","Language":"Lezgian"},{"CountryCode":"AZE","Language":"Russian"},{"CountryCode":"BDI","Language":"French"},{"CountryCode":"BDI","Language":"Kirundi"},{"CountryCode":"BDI","Language":"Swahili"},{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"Arabic"},{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"Dutch"},{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"French"},{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"German"},{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"Italian"},{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"Turkish"},{"CountryCode":"BEN","Language":"Adja"},{"CountryCode":"BEN","Language":"Aizo"}]
```

You can then simply assign that to an array. For example:

var countries = $.parseJSON('[{"CountryCode":"ABW","Language":"Dutch"},{"CountryCode":"ABW","Language":"English"},{"CountryCode":"ABW","Language":"Papiamento"},{"CountryCode":"ABW","Language":"Spanish"},{"CountryCode":"AFG","Language":"Balochi"},{"CountryCode":"AFG","Language":"Dari"},{"CountryCode":"AFG","Language":"Pashto"},{"CountryCode":"AFG","Language":"Turkmenian"},{"CountryCode":"AFG","Language":"Uzbek"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Ambo"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Chokwe"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Kongo"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Luchazi"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Luimbe-nganguela"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Luvale"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Mbundu"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Nyaneka-nkhumbi"},{"CountryCode":"AGO","Language":"Ovimbundu"},{"CountryCode":"AIA","Language":"English"},{"CountryCode":"ALB","Language":"Albaniana"},{"CountryCode":"ALB","Language":"Greek"},{"CountryCode":"ALB","Language":"Macedonian"},{"CountryCode":"AND","Language":"Catalan"},{"CountryCode":"AND","Language":"French"},{"CountryCode":"AND","Language":"Portuguese"},{"CountryCode":"AND","Language":"Spanish"},{"CountryCode":"ANT","Language":"Dutch"},{"CountryCode":"ANT","Language":"English"},{"CountryCode":"ANT","Language":"Papiamento"},{"CountryCode":"ARE","Language":"Arabic"},{"CountryCode":"ARE","Language":"Hindi"},{"CountryCode":"ARG","Language":"Indian Languages"},{"CountryCode":"ARG","Language":"Italian"},{"CountryCode":"ARG","Language":"Spanish"},{"CountryCode":"ARM","Language":"Armenian"},{"CountryCode":"ARM","Language":"Azerbaijani"},{"CountryCode":"ASM","Language":"English"},{"CountryCode":"ASM","Language":"Samoan"},{"CountryCode":"ASM","Language":"Tongan"},{"CountryCode":"ATG","Language":"Creole English"},{"CountryCode":"ATG","Language":"English"},{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Arabic"},{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Canton Chinese"},{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"English"},{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"German"},{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Greek"},{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Italian"},{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Serbo-Croatian"},{"CountryCode":"AUS","Language":"Vietnamese"},{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Czech"},{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"German"},{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Hungarian"},{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Polish"},{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Romanian"},{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Serbo-Croatian"},{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Slovene"},{"CountryCode":"AUT","Language":"Turkish"},{"CountryCode":"AZE","Language":"Armenian"},{"CountryCode":"AZE","Language":"Azerbaijani"},{"CountryCode":"AZE","Language":"Lezgian"},{"CountryCode":"AZE","Language":"Russian"},{"CountryCode":"BDI","Language":"French"},{"CountryCode":"BDI","Language":"Kirundi"},{"CountryCode":"BDI","Language":"Swahili"},{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"Arabic"},{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"Dutch"},{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"French"},{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"German"},{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"Italian"},{"CountryCode":"BEL","Language":"Turkish"},{"CountryCode":"BEN","Language":"Adja"},{"CountryCode":"BEN","Language":"Aizo"}]');

alert(countries.length);